# Change fragment layout portrait to landscape

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I work with fragment but my problem is that : 
When I change orientation, if I had 2 columns in my scrollView they still in the screen even it is portrait, or If I had one column in portrait mode when I pass to landscape I had only one column.

I had 3 layout with the same name only number of columns which change,
I put it all in folder layout, layout-land and layout-port.

**What I need is that when I passe from portrait to landscape I would passe from 2 columns to one, and vice versa.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the one layout from the `layout` folder, since you only need `layout-land` and `layout-port`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just put it all in folder layout, layout-land and layout-port to make it work. There are 3 more steps you need to do:
1. Create a layout.xml file in values folder
2. Put xml layout with 2 column in layout-land and layout with 1 column in layout-port 
3. In onCreateView() in your fragment, inflate the layout's name in layout.xml file instead current layout.

For more details, I'll show you some code:
You're gonna write a MainFragment and you create a fragment_main.xml for its layout. What you need to do is:

1. Write fragment_main.xml in layout folder (1 column layout)
2. Write fragment_main_land.xml in layout folder (2 column layout)
3. Create layouts.xml file in values-land folder with the code lines

       `<resources>
           <item name="layout_main" type="layout">@layout/fragment_main</item>
       </resources>`
4. Create layouts.xml file in values-land folder with the code lines

   `<resources>
           <item name="layout_main" type="layout">@layout/fragment_main_land</item>
       </resources>`
5. on onCreateView method of MainFragment, inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, null);

Comment: thank's for the response but can you please explain more the 3th point ? If you have more code java or xml it will be good

Comment: I edited my answer for clearly explanation. Please take a look @Euphor08

Comment: thank's so I don't need to use onConfigurationChanged right now ? I use what you're givinig me right ?

Comment: Ya, for sure, you do not need touch onConfigurationChanged anymore. Just do above things and android care everything for us ^_^

Comment: Sorry my friend but it doesn't work my fragment destroyed when I change orientation, I add this **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"** but the layout column's not changing :/
if you have a working example could you send it to me at ettaheri.nizar@gmail.com

Comment: I don't have example for it but, in my current project, I follow this page http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html and everything works perfect on my complexity layout. Try it! and I also don't use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  in manifest

Comment: Hey bro it didn't work, really I passed all the day and I'm blocked so could you please help me ?

Comment: @Euphor08, I can't let you share your project with me and I fix it for you bro. Let's create a totally new project from scratch, create a simple layout for test purpose, step by step. I'm sure that code would work and you can find out what the problem is

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    //change your desigen by java code
} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
     //change your desigen by java code
}
```

Comment: it will works or not If had the same layout's name ?
sorry for the stupide question